# How to host django app on ionos's VPS, i get invalid page on my ip:8000

Tags: python, django, ionos

How to host django app on ionos's VPS

I have purchased the cheapest VPS plan of ionos and now i want to host my django app, but when i execute 'python manage.py runserver' command and go to my_ip:8000 it shows invalid page on the browser, can anyone help me???

Comment: do you run a windows or unix VPS? what about firewall? do you see the access in the terminal of the VPS?

Answer (score 0):

to make the server available to the outside world you need to use

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and the firewall needs to have  port 8000 opened

Comment: still it's not showing but when i go to my ip without port it shows 'welcome to ngnix'  page

Comment: please show how you setup the VPS. Above means you have nginx configured on port 80 but it obviously does not forward to port 8000 but shows default static page